# Line connecting dots of same ID in nested ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a set of data to study the response to a treatment in both sexes. Either treatment or control vehicle is administered and the variable of interest measured at time 0 and 30 days for every individual:

| Sex | Time | Group | ID | Variable |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| M | t0 | control | ID01 | 87.4468574183993 |
| M | t0 | treatment | ID02 | 61.6036264109425 |
| M | t0 | control | ID03 | 87.1487529366277 |
| M | t0 | treatment | ID04 | 50.6166256731376 |
| M | t0 | control | ID05 | 72.9583341162652 |
| M | t0 | treatment | ID06 | 56.7137802368961 |
| M | t0 | control | ID07 | 65.8371140481904 |
| M | t0 | treatment | ID08 | 86.0453418688849 |
| M | t0 | control | ID09 | 83.5156044340692 |
| M | t0 | treatment | ID10 | 68.5201310901903 |
| M | t30 | control | ID01 | 84.504537214525 |
| M | t30 | treatment | ID02 | 56.6733720363118 |
| M | t30 | control | ID03 | 91.0738771315664 |
| M | t30 | treatment | ID04 | 94.9689620872959 |
| M | t30 | control | ID05 | 76.23775213724 |
| M | t30 | treatment | ID06 | 74.8982135788538 |
| M | t30 | control | ID07 | 80.9279862442054 |
| M | t30 | treatment | ID08 | 51.5291749034077 |
| M | t30 | control | ID09 | 85.7785020256415 |
| M | t30 | treatment | ID10 | 51.461190963164 |
| F | t0 | control | ID11 | 52.1936888922937 |
| F | t0 | treatment | ID12 | 91.9786257203668 |
| F | t0 | control | ID13 | 83.2809177343734 |
| F | t0 | treatment | ID14 | 71.7776856268756 |
| F | t0 | control | ID15 | 89.8885271861218 |
| F | t0 | treatment | ID16 | 84.3541337642819 |
| F | t0 | control | ID17 | 87.5198906287551 |
| F | t0 | treatment | ID18 | 94.8092532227747 |
| F | t0 | control | ID19 | 56.6507609561086 |
| F | t0 | treatment | ID20 | 72.2115040174685 |
| F | t30 | control | ID11 | 53.5416435450315 |
| F | t30 | treatment | ID12 | 61.9461603346281 |
| F | t30 | control | ID13 | 63.9171704184264 |
| F | t30 | treatment | ID14 | 73.8425903371535 |
| F | t30 | control | ID15 | 77.3780003190041 |
| F | t30 | treatment | ID16 | 80.7108032982796 |
| F | t30 | control | ID17 | 82.9249111004174 |
| F | t30 | treatment | ID18 | 72.6573116029613 |
| F | t30 | control | ID19 | 88.3334786165506 |
| F | t30 | treatment | ID20 | 50.722946121823 |

I managed to generate a suitable nested plot:

```
ggplot(mydata, aes(x = Sex, y = Variable, fill = Time)) +  facet_grid(. ~ Group) +   geom_boxplot(alpha = 0.80,outlier.colour = NA) +   geom_point(aes(fill = Time), size   2, shape = 21, position = position_jitterdodge(0))
```

[image: the first plot I obtained]

But I would like to include lines joining the dots belonging to a same individual, something like this (I added the black lines as an example using a software for image edition)

[image: the plot I want]

I tried:

```
ggplot(mydata, aes(x = Sex, y = Variable, fill = Time)) +   facet_grid(. ~ Group) +   geom_boxplot(alpha = 0.80,outlier.colour = NA) +   geom_point(aes(fill = Time), size = 2, shape = 21, position = position_jitterdodge(0))+   geom_line(aes(group=interaction(ID,Sex)), size=0.3, alpha=0.8)
```

But the lines were not correctly drawn

[image: the second plot I obtained]

I also looked at this solution:
[How to add lines connecting dots in boxplot in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67845039/how-to-add-lines-connecting-dots-in-boxplot-in-r)

But I would not like to add more panels to my plot.
Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option to achieve your desired result would be to manually do the dodging for the `geom_line` by computing the `x` positions like so:

```r
library(ggplot2)

width <- .75

mydata$x_line <- as.numeric(factor(mydata$Sex)) + 
  ifelse(mydata$Time == "t0", -1, 1) * width / 4

ggplot(mydata, aes(x = Sex, y = Variable, fill = Time)) +
  facet_grid(. ~ Group, scales = "free_x") +
  geom_boxplot(alpha = 0.80, outlier.colour = NA, position = position_dodge(width)) +
  geom_point(aes(group = Time), size = 2, shape = 21, position = position_dodge(width)) +
  geom_line(aes(x = x_line, group = ID), size = 0.3, alpha = 0.8)
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
mydata <- data.frame(
  Sex = c(
    "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M",
    "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M",
    "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F",
    "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F"
  ),
  Time = c(
    "t0", "t0", "t0", "t0", "t0",
    "t0", "t0", "t0", "t0", "t0", "t30", "t30", "t30", "t30",
    "t30", "t30", "t30", "t30", "t30", "t30", "t0", "t0",
    "t0", "t0", "t0", "t0", "t0", "t0", "t0", "t0", "t30", "t30",
    "t30", "t30", "t30", "t30", "t30", "t30", "t30", "t30"
  ),
  Group = c(
    "control", "treatment",
    "control", "treatment", "control", "treatment", "control",
    "treatment", "control", "treatment", "control", "treatment",
    "control", "treatment", "control", "treatment", "control",
    "treatment", "control", "treatment", "control",
    "treatment", "control", "treatment", "control", "treatment",
    "control", "treatment", "control", "treatment", "control",
    "treatment", "control", "treatment", "control", "treatment",
    "control", "treatment", "control", "treatment"
  ),
  ID = c(
    "ID01", "ID02", "ID03", "ID04",
    "ID05", "ID06", "ID07", "ID08", "ID09", "ID10", "ID01",
    "ID02", "ID03", "ID04", "ID05", "ID06", "ID07", "ID08",
    "ID09", "ID10", "ID11", "ID12", "ID13", "ID14", "ID15",
    "ID16", "ID17", "ID18", "ID19", "ID20", "ID11", "ID12",
    "ID13", "ID14", "ID15", "ID16", "ID17", "ID18", "ID19",
    "ID20"
  ),
  Variable = c(
    87.4468574183993,
    61.6036264109425, 87.1487529366277, 50.6166256731376, 72.9583341162652,
    56.7137802368961, 65.8371140481904, 86.0453418688849,
    83.5156044340692, 68.5201310901903, 84.504537214525,
    56.6733720363118, 91.0738771315664, 94.9689620872959,
    76.23775213724, 74.8982135788538, 80.9279862442054,
    51.5291749034077, 85.7785020256415, 51.461190963164, 52.1936888922937,
    91.9786257203668, 83.2809177343734, 71.7776856268756,
    89.8885271861218, 84.3541337642819, 87.5198906287551,
    94.8092532227747, 56.6507609561086, 72.2115040174685,
    53.5416435450315, 61.9461603346281, 63.9171704184264,
    73.8425903371535, 77.3780003190041, 80.7108032982796,
    82.9249111004174, 72.6573116029613, 88.3334786165506, 50.722946121823
  )
)
```